# Convert nested loops into a Stream

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

I want to replace nested `for` loops in the following code with streams:

```
private boolean check(St st) {
    List<Co> prereqs = getCoPrereqs();
    
    for (Co prereq : prereqs) {
        
        List<En> stEns = st.getEns();
        boolean flag = false;
        
        for (En en : stEns) {
            if (en.getCo().equals(prereq) && en.getGr() != null) {
                if (en.hasPassedCo()) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (!flag)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The two loops and the variable flag is causing confusion. I am not sure if this can be converted to streams totally.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your code somewhat by doing the following:

- removing the `boolean` flag. It isn't necessary.
- get the `List<En>` just one time outside of the Prereq loop. You can reiterate the original as often as necessary.

The major difference is to check for a `false` return from `en.hasPassedCo()` and return `false` immediately.  Once the iterations are complete, then return `true`.

```
private boolean check(St st) {
        List<Co> prereqs = getCoPrereqs();
        
        List<En> stEns = st.getEns();

        for (Co prereq : prereqs) {           
            for (En en : stEns) {
                if (en.getCo().equals(prereq) && en.getGr() != null) {
                    if (!en.hasPassedCo()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

I'm not certain that streams would improve this (at least not knowing more about the relationships of the fields to each other).  Also, it doesn't make sense how `Co` relates to `en.getCo`.  Seems to me that something like `prereqs.contains(en.getCo())` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can use nested streams with `allMatch`.

I'm saying "probably" because I can't be sure that the code you've proved does what expected, types name are not self-explanatory at all (names in the code **matter a lot**) and you have not accompanied the code with any explanations.

If I understood your code correctly, you need to validate every `Co` object returned by `getCoPrereqs()` and that entails checking  each `Co` object against `En` object from a `List<En>` which should be extracted from the method parameter.

That's how it might look like:

```
private boolean check(St st){
    
    return getCoPrereqs().stream()
        .allMatch((Co prereq) -> st.getEns().stream()
            .allMatch((En en) -> en.getCo().equals(prereq)
                            && en.getGr() != null
                            && en.hasPassedCo()
                     ));
}
```

For readability reasons (to make it more easier to compare stream with loops), I've used explicitly typed lambda expressions (the common practice is to omit types for brevity and let the type inference do the job).